# Issue connecting magento soap api from laravel 4.2 application

Tags: php, laravel, api, magento

In the system, soap api part is done with magento.

**app/config/api.php**

```
<?php
return array (
    /**
     * Magento Api
     */
    'mage_soap_api_url'         => 'http://url/',
    'mage_soap_api_user'        => 'username',
    'mage_soap_api_key'         => 'password',
    'mage_soap_api_path'        => '/var/www/ecomm'

);
```

And it is working in the staging server.But when I try to access this magento part at staging to locally implemented laravel 4.2 project, I'm getting this error.

> PHP Fatal error:  {closure}(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/ecomm/app/Mage.php'
>   (include_path='/var/www/html/local/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
>   in /var/www/html/local/app/routes.php on line 125

**routes.php**

```
Route::any('/customer/account/logout', function () {
    $api_path = Config::get('api.mage_soap_api_path');
    require_once("{$api_path}app/Mage.php");
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session->logout();
    Session::put('customer', null);
    return Redirect::to('/login');
});
```

Is there any permission to be set to access it(magento soap api) locally. Actually I'm laravel developer. so not familiar with magento.

It will be great if somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was the permission issue. I don't have access to staging magento api from my local sytem. They have resticted it. I setup it locally and linked db. now it's working.